# Is there a closed form for $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt {n!}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

This is a curiosity question.

Let's consider the following sum:
$$S=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{ n !}}$$

The question asked to prove its convergence, which I did using the ratio test. So I tried to find a closed form for the this sum but without luck.

**My question**

> 1) Is there a closed form for $S$? (very likely no).
>   2) If the answer is no can we prove that there is no closed form for $S$ rigorously?

Thanks,

Comment: To prove or disprove 2) rigorously, there must be a rigorous definition of "closed form".

Comment: It is already non-trivial to prove the limit is $e$ without the square-root, if you use the $\lim_{x \to \infty} (1+1/x)^x$ definition of $e$. So I suspect you are right there's probably no closed formula in terms of known constants and functions, or at least, it would be very hard to determine.

Comment: It seems quite unlikely.   See http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=5628902 or http://www.wilmott.com/messageview.cfm?catid=34&threadid=44616 (which can be found by computing the sum numerically and googling the resulting value).

Comment: @ajotatxe Closed form $=$ combination (sum, product and composition) of some usual functions $F$  applied to some usuel values V. where for example $F=\left\{x\to \sin x,x\to \cos x,x\to e^x\right\}\cup\mathbb{Q}[X]$ and $V=\mathbb{Q}\cup \{e,\pi\}$

Comment: "Closed form number" has (essentially) no non-trivial theory.  Unlike "closed form function" which has many interesting non-trivial results.  So: even if you prove $\sum x^n/\sqrt{n!}$ is not an elementary function, it does not follow that $\sum 1/\sqrt{n!}$ is "not a closed form number".

Comment: @GEdgar but I think that the two notions are related, in fact I could define (this is a definition and it defines almost what we intuit by closed form number) the set of closed form numbers $C$ by two assertions: every algebraic number is an element of $C$ and we could add for example $e\in C$ and $\pi\in C$ and the second assertion $\forall a\in C$, and for every closed form function $f$, we have $f(a)\in A$. What do you think about this definition?

Comment: @Elaqqad: That could well be one of the definitions that has been tried, but has no non-trivial theorems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$S(a)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(n!)^a}$ converges for all $a>0$, however, the only **known** closed forms are $S(1)=e$,

and $S(2)=I_0(2)$, see [Bessel function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) for more information.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

IIRC there's a contour-integral expression for convolution of power series that gives the function $h(x)=f(x)\circ g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_ng_nx^n$ in terms of the functions $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_nx^n$ and $g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty g_nx^n$; you can invert that to get an integral equation for the power series $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{n!}}$ since the convolution $f\circ f$ is equal to $e^x$. I believe it can be proven with some differential Galois theory that $f()$ is non-elementary, though, so this may not be any help in getting special values of the function.  For more references, you might try Melzak's [*Companion to Concrete Mathematics*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471593389), which uses the convolution formula to get an expression for the aforementioned Bessel functions.